# How to use material-ui framework?

Tags: material-design, material-ui

I'm planning to use Material-UI CSS framework (http://material-ui.com) in order to design front-end of a website, but I don't have any idea about how to use this framework.

I'm not familiar a lot with NPM, Browserify, etc. I just need to know how shall I start in order to learn the way to use this CSS framework.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Found a solution? I am still wandering on how to start development. I am in the exact same state as you have mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @bozzmob and all, I can recommend you my [Razzle Material UI Styled Example](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example).

Comment: Also here is an article of mine about how to use Material-UI: [Material-UI: Get started (Fast!) ⚡ React 16+](https://www.codementor.io/kireerik/material-ui-get-started-fast-react-16-fjan7erke)

Answer (score 42):

Don't be intimidated by the (apparent) complexity of webpack and other (great) build tools, and don't be discouraged by envious jerks who say things like "To be honest, I think you got a big problem to use this stuff."

The reason why the material-ui implementation (usage) is based on these tools is because is currently the best way to write software and understanding this and other frameworks is a great way to learn why this is the "right" way, and become proficient at writing quality modular code.

Webpack, and the other build tools, exist for one purpose: to create one "main" file from your app's source code that can be read and delivered to your users' browser in an efficient manner. Long gone are the days when we  would write a bunch of include (script) tags for every resource (file) we need in our pages and thus have our users wait until all these were downloaded from our server (or multiple locations e.g.: cdns) and then the page would load. The efficiency is based on the fact that you can deliver one (often minified/compressed) file that contains all your code and any code it depends on (e.g. React or even jQuery).

Build tools accomplish this by asking you 3 things: what file to start with (entry main file), what tools (loaders) to use to process non-native JavaScript code within your code (scss, jsx, etc) and what file to create as the result (converted and minified output). This output file will be the one you use in your html import/script tag. It will contain your code plus all other dependencies, which would be a nightmare to include and resolve manually yourself. [Here](http://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/05/15/howto-setup-webpack-on-es6-react-application-with-sass.html) is a good beginners' guide.

Material-ui, like many other frameworks (reason why I took the time to explain all of the above) is built with modularity in mind: pieces of code can be "glued" or "pieced" together like Legos, in order to easily build bigger parts. You do this by simply including the components you need in any component you create. They are React components which are a simple way to define (write/create) the "building blocks" of your site/app. There are tons of great videos and tutorials to get you started with React (my favorite is reactjsprogram.com by Tyler McGinnis).

To get you started  with material-ui, they have created a couple of examples to get started [using webpack](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui-webpack-example). Follow the simple steps to install npm and the dependencies (you can find them in package.json) and open the /src directory in your editor. You'll figure it  out in no time.

You are in the right track with the right attitude by asking questions, learning to be a good developer, researching and trying to find the easiest way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: the "using webpack" link is broken

Comment: Is it possible to use it without React? Just a `.css` and `.js` and if possibly a gem?

Answer (score 24):

Had pretty much the same problem.  Wanted a simple way to start using material-ui without the gibberish.  Here's what I did:

```
npm install material-ui
npm install -g webpack
webpack node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js material-ui.js
```

This gave me a javascript file, `material-ui.js`, I could then include in my HTML.  In my case I'm using electron, so this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>examples</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script>
        require('./material-ui.js')
    </script>

    <script type="text/babel">      
        import React from 'react';
        import FlatButton from 'material-ui/lib/flat-button';


        const FlatButtonExampleSimple = () => (
          <div>
            <FlatButton label="Default" />
            <FlatButton label="Primary" primary={true} />
            <FlatButton label="Secondary" secondary={true} />
            <FlatButton label="Disabled" disabled={true} />
          </div>
        );      

        ReactDOM.render(
          <FlatButtonExampleSimple />,
          document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you insert `npm install material-ui` ?

Comment: That's a command you run from the shell.  Doesn't go into any file.

Comment: But where in the command prompt? Anywhere I try it says " 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Install node.  npm is included. Follow the install direction https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: webpack node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js material-ui.js => ERROR in multi node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js material-ui.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js' in './'
 @ multi node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js material-ui.js

Comment: As of 2020-03-30, this no longer works.  Material ui is now imported using @material-ui/core (at a minimum).  I tried changing the command to use @material-ui, but there is no longer a lib directory so the command doesn't work.  But I do like the idea. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Material-UI is a set of React components in addition to being a CSS framework.  I don't know if you can get much use out of it without understanding React.

The easiest way to get started is to install the [examples](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/examples) and start from there.

If you don't want to deal with a frontend framework like React, and just want CSS and JS files with a setup time as quick as Bootstrap, check out the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) library.

Comment: I tried using Materialize, and honestly, it will get you into the very same mess of tooling as everything else.  The CSS it generates is highly redundant, so it's difficult to do much meaningful customization without editing the SASS source code and building that.

Comment: Materialize is only running on Chrome, IE, Firefox and Safari

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I think you got a big problem to use this stuff.

Firstly, it depends on Facebook's View framework called React so you have to know well some basic things.

Secondly,React is totally a javascript stuff and if you use it by coding plain javascript, that would be an other big problem which may stop you.otherwise if you use it's syntax sugar called jsx, you still need to pay plenty of times to learn well it so that you could know how React work and then you could use it in your project.

Thirdly, before the above mentioned happen, there are still several things required that you dont need to know well NodeJs or webpack or NPM but at least you should know well how to use them as the simple tools.

So, is it a must that you have no other choice but have to use this stuff and only act it as a simple css framework?

If not! you can give up now except you are ready to learn tons of dependencies!!!

If yes! I advice you to install nodejs first and then install npm and then use npm to install react maybe you still need to install some tools like babel browserify or webpack(the best) and then dive into React and then you could begin learning how to use MUI~ sounds...mass

There isnt a quick pickup way for MUI just like they said!

Comment: What you say about React is true. However, even if you know how to use React (I sort of do), material-ui requires you to learn to integrate with a whole bunch of development tools like browserify or webpack and/or gulp. Is that really necessary? I mean, can it not be just a JS file I can include similar to React, Babel etc.?

Comment: Nope, I don't think it's necessary. As you know, MUI is not just a single file, it contains lots of components, so if use webpack or browserify or glup to work with would be better. I don't think it's a must, of course you can include each single file by using the require function or import keyword of ES6. If you have installed the whole MUI as a dependency via npm, you can include each file whatever you want.

Comment: There are lots of great resources to get started with using Material UI. Here is a link to the documentation where you can find example projects to get started. https://material-ui.com/getting-started/example-projects/

Answer (score 2):

If you use the react+redux, you can use the 
https://github.com/takanabe/react-redux-material_ui-boilerplate

template.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [sample node project](https://github.com/sevenleaps/react-webpack-wrapper-example) showing how to bundle a react component for consumption in non-react websites using webpack. It's a similar approach to dkantowitz's, except it removes the need to introduce react or reactDom to the consuming website.

The example as it is would need to be extended to allow use with multiple components (like material-ui is) but I think it provides a good starting point for seeing whats involved with webpack and babel etc